# how to create one separate class for all api link and calling that api to all view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, api, nsurlconnection

I am having login, register, table view, collection view, map view controller. In all these controller classes i am having separate `myphp api url`. My base url is `"Http://some url"`. And in my all view controller i am calling like this  `""Http://some url/login.php", "Http://some url/register/php"`.Like wise i am calling each url in all view controller.Instead of that, it is possible to create one class and make all url there.And calling the name of url like, `login.php or login`,Like wise in all my view controller??

If possible can any one suggest me some code example,so that it will very help full.

I am using swift 2.0

Thanks

Comment: What you've just described is a perfect demonstration of OO programming, but also fits the mold of Apple's MVC architecture for iOS apps. Yes what you're wanting to do is completely possible and can be done with a class just like anything else in OOP can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Make a New File Which should be inherited from NSObject..

Like common.h and common.m

And Store all your URL's in common class shown in the image as MACRO in .h file

WhenEver using the URL's just add this common class to your view controller and use it .

[image]

Comment: But can you just describe me , in my loginViewcontroler.swift , registervc.swift .How can i call these url name to use in my all view controolers??

Comment: that means i have to add all my url ans #deifne . Its clear.But how can i add to all my view controleller. Like `import common` or ???

Comment: Yes import common.h in which ever file you want to access these URL's and Use the macro.

Comment: Like in common.h
Add #define BASEURL http://google.com
and include this file in viewcontroller.m 
And where ever you want to use google.com , just use BASEURL , at runtime Your BASEURL will be replaced by http://google.com.

Comment: ok, but i am using swift. But can you give atleast one example for this url "http://www.myphp,com.login"..Using #define

Comment: like this way is correct `#define BASEURL = http://www.myphp.com/login.php ` Is this correct??

Comment: It doesnot matter weather you are working with swift and objective c , just try to understand , define macros in common file and import this common file in whatever viewcontroller you want and USE BASEURL (Macro Name) at those places where you want to use your url .

Comment: #define BASEURL @"http://www.myphp.com/login.php"
 No =  bcs it is macro......macro is defined in this way

Comment: thanks, i also have one question but not yet get the answer.. Can you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267662/use-single-table-view-controller-for-each-collection-view-cell-press

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit

struct APIURLFactory {
    let baseURL : NSURL!

    init(baseURL: NSURL) {
        self.baseURL = baseURL
    }

    func relativeURL(path: String) -> NSURL? {
        return NSURL(string: path, relativeToURL: baseURL)?.absoluteURL
    }

    func relativeURLString(path: String) -> String? {
        return NSURL(string: path, relativeToURL: baseURL)?.absoluteString
    }
}

let myFactory = APIURLFactory(baseURL: NSURL(string: "http://my.php.api.com/")!)

// This yields the URL http://my.php.api.com/login.php
let loginURL = myFactory.relativeURL("login.php")

// This yields the URL http://my.php.api.com/register/php
let registerURL = myFactory.relativeURL("register/php")
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution. But can you just describe me , in my loginViewcontroler.swift , registervc.swift .How can i call these url name to use in my all view controolers??

Comment: these all code are i have to imlement as NSObject classes or nomal view controller classes??

Comment: thanks, i also have one question but not yet get the answer.. Can you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267662/use-single-table-view-controller-for-each-collection-view-cell-press