# how to pass id with name. So by click any cell i need to display the respective name id in collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i have one collection view and i am displaying some name and images.Its working fine.But i also have some id.so when my first cell is clicked, i need to display the name with respective id.

my full code:

```
import UIKit

class popVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


    // use array to store the name and images fro collection view
    var tableData: [String] = ["RESTAURANTS", "BANKS", "COFFEE","PIZZA", "HOTELS", "TAXI", "RESTAURANTS", "BANKS", "COFFEE","PIZZA", "HOTELS", "TAXI", "RESTAURANTS","BANKS", "COFFEE","PIZZA", "HOTELS", "TAXI","RESTAURANTS", "BANKS", "COFFEE","PIZZA", "HOTELS", "TAXI", "RESTAURANTS", "BANKS", "COFFEE","PIZZA", "HOTELS", "TAXI"]
    var tableImages: [String] = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png", "img6.png","img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png", "img6.png","img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png", "img6.png","img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png", "img6.png","img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png", "img6.png",]


    var idnumber: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12","13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18","20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25","26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
// collection view delegate

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: colvwCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! colvwCell
        cell.lblCell.text = tableData[indexPath.row]


        cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(named: tableImages[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }


   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    }


    // Action method for dismis the view controlelr
    @IBAction func dismissVC(sender: AnyObject) {

        var presentingViewController: UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false) {
            // go back to MainMenuView as the eyes of the user
            presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)


            //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }


        //}
    }
    // collection view cell space and size 
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width/3) - 10, (self.view.frame.size.width/3) - 15);

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

This code will display the name with images as in array like my data .But when i click my first cell, i need to display the id of that cell

For example :

if i click the `first cell` ( Restaurant, img1.png ). in my console i need to display id = 1 as per my hard coded value in my code.

How to do that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of one of the delegate methods

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
print(idnumber[indexPath.row])
}
```

This is for printing to console, if you need to do anything else, you can always access the id in this way

```
idnumber[indexPath.row]
```

Now I know that you would like pass this id to another view controller. Let's assume your next viewController is called YourViewController and has a global variable called id, your segue id is "yourSegueID". I hope you I'll be able to present you the concept of using prepareForSegue method.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if(segue.identifier == "yourSegueID"){
          var cell: UICollectionViewCell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
          var indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
          let vc:YourViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! YourViewController
          vc.id = idnumber[indexPath.row]
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But based on that i need to pass this id to another view controller. so that , in next view controller i have one table view. If my id = 1 means, it have to display name belong to restaurants. If my id = 2 means. it have to display the name belong to bank.. So how can i navigate to another view controller with this id. And based on my id how can i display the data??

Comment: thanks for your code.if possible, i am having one table view controller and i need to pass many data .I already have asked thsi doubt in SO.But not yet get solution, If possible can you please.Your code is quit able to understand easy.

Comment: here is my post question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267662/use-single-table-view-controller-for-each-collection-view-cell-press

Comment: here is my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267662/use-single-table-view-controller-for-each-collection-view-cell-press

Answer (score 1):

The key is in use of indexPath.

```
 if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    let selectedData = tableData[indexPath.row] as String
                }
```